# Proper syntax to read and write byte array in Cap'n Proto?

Tags: c++, capnproto

Let's say I have an array:

```
struct UUID
{
    char data[16];
};
```

And I have it like so in the schema:

```
struct UUID
{
    value @0 : Data;
}
```

What's the proper way to read and write this field? It looks like I should be able to wrap a *capnp::Data::Reader* around the array and use the builder's setValue(), but the syntax is really non-obvious.

The other way is also somewhat mysterious. How do I populate the array when deserializing? My current approach involves a memcpy, but I assume there's a Cap'n Proto way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Data::Reader` is essentially a `kj::ArrayPtr<const kj::byte>`.

`Data::Builder` is essentially a `kj::ArrayPtr<kj::byte>`.

`kj::byte` is a typedef for `unsigned char`.

`kj::ArrayPtr` is essentially a pointer/size pair. It implements `operator[]`, `size()`, `begin()`, `end()`, etc. `begin()` and `end()` return raw pointers, not a special iterator type.

Building:

```
UUID::Builder builder = ...;
kj::byte buf[16] = ...;

// option 1
builder.setData(kj::arrayPtr(buf, sizeof(buf)));

// option 2
memcpy(builder.initData(16).begin(), buf, 16);
```

Reading:

```
UUID::Reader reader = ...;
auto data = reader.getData();

// option 1
// void someFunction(kj::byte* ptr, size_t size)
someFunction(data.begin(), data.size());

// option 2
kj::byte buf[16];
KJ_REQUIRE(data.size() == sizeof(buf));
memcpy(buf, data.begin(), sizeof(buf));
```